# shell script which opens python with arguments to python script

Tags: python, shell, command-line-arguments

I want to debug some Python code in PyCharm but the repository I got the code from uses a shell script of the form

```
python main.py arg1 ... argN
```

which is run from the command line. The main.py module in turn has a `if __name__ == '__main__':` part which uses argparse to parse the arguments passed via the script.

How can I write a Python script which also calls the **main** of main.py without touching main.py?

Comment: This is part of why it's good practice to put your logic in a `main` function, and then have the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block just call that function. Extra credit if one accepts an argv on the main function's parameter list (passing it through to argparse), with `sys.argv` passed in that location by the main block.

Comment: ...because yes, the code you're describing makes it unnecessarily hard to invoke its entry point -- but really, that's a misfeature *in that code*. (It also makes some kinds of code inspection tricky -- tools that import modules and then walk their AST for the purpose of static checking don't work if the function isn't *in* the generated AST when imported as a non-`main` name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a script for that. You can [Edit Run Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) in Pycharm to emulate command line arguments passed to the script.

Follow these steps:

1. Open `Edit Configurations...`:

   [image: An image of the Pycharm window, highlighting the option "Edit configurations" that is shown after clicking the drop-down menu next to the run symbol at the top-right corner]
2. Make sure you edit the configuration of your `main.py`:

   [image: An image showing the "Edit configurations" window, with the name of the current file highlighted at the left pane]
3. Then, simply add the command line arguments, just as you would in the command line, under the `parameters` field:

   [image: An image showing the "Edit configurations" window, with the "Parameters" input field highlighted]
4. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. Run regularly using the green arrow (or right-click and Run)

---

If you actually have that shell script, you can run it directly by adding a new configuration. On the `Configurations` window press the <kbd>+</kbd> on the top-left corner and choose `Shell Script`. Indicate the path and any option you want to pass and run.

Answer (score 0):

For example: define new `def main():` function and move all your `if __name__ == '__main__':` stuff there, then rewrite `main.py` as:

```
def main():
    <original "if __name__ == '__main__'" stuff>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

, and then call main() function from an external python script.